# Multi part identifier in Microsoft SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I'm migrating a SQL Server 6.5 database to SQL Server 2012. Migration went well but one of the software using this database performs a strange query:

```
UPDATE myTable SET Field1='',Field2=0, a.Field3=14 WHERE Field10=1
```

The problem lies of course with the identifier ('a') before Field3. There are no views, aliases or join with that name but for SQL Server 6,5 that is a valid query.

Since I'm not familiar with SQL Server 6.5, do any of you remember the meaning of this syntax?

The software using this query is an old one of which I don't have any sources (and the company that made it is now closed...), so changing the query is not an option.

The full query is

```
UPDATE SituazioneMacchina 
SET DatiSetPointSpediti=''
,   SpedMappa=0
,   NrRichMappa=0
,   DatiSetPoint=''
,   a.IDProduzione=14
WHERE NumMacchina=1
```

If I change "a.IDProduzione" with something like "fasdffas.IDProduzione", the query still works in SQL Server 6.5

Comment: The complete query is as follow:
    UPDATE SituazioneMacchina SET DatiSetPointSpediti='',SpedMappa=0,NrRichMappa=0,DatiSetPoint='', a.IDProduzione=14 WHERE NumMacchina=1

If I change "a.IDProduzione" with something like "fasdffas.IDProduzione", the query still works in SQL 6.5

Comment: If the query became `UPDATE a SET ... FROM myTable AS a WHERE ...` that should make it valid, yes?

Comment: Looks like this was fixed by 7.0. I can't get it to accept this syntax. 4.21 is fine with it, though, essentially ignoring the table alias.

Comment: @db2 - You still have 4.21 running?

Comment: @MartinSmith Doesn't everybody have a 4.21 VM sitting around? :)

Comment: @db2 - Not me but with your profile description I would have been disappointed if you hadn't I suppose  ;-)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As you say the query doesn't make any sense.

Probably just a parser bug in 6.5. There have been a few similar other issues `ORDER BY nonsensealias.somecolumn` worked [until 2005](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ms143359%28v=sql.90%29.aspx) with the SQL Server 2000 behavior being

> Column names in the ORDER BY clause are resolved to columns listed in
>   the select list, regardless if they are qualified. For example, the
>   following query executes without error:

```
USE pubs
SELECT au_fname AS 'FName',
  au_lname AS 'LName'
FROM authors a
ORDER BY a.LName
```

> SQL Server ignores the qualifier a in the ORDER BY clause and resolves
>   the column name LName to the select list.

and there is still [a similar issue](http://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/311881/sql-server-incorrectly-accepts-prefixes-in-column-list-of-insert-statements#details) for `INSERT` statements where the following syntax is accepted.

```
CREATE TABLE nisse(hult int NOT NULL)
go
INSERT nisse(ab.xx.hult)
VALUES(12)
go
DROP TABLE nisse
```

Comment: Thanks Martin. I'v tried the same query in SQL 2008 with SQL 2000 compatibility level and it doesn't work. Maybe the bug was resolved in SQL 2000.
I'm gonna investigate for one more day and then I'll mark your answer as accepted.

Comment: @Nicola `query in SQL 2008 with SQL 2000 compatibility level` This changes some things around parsing and tokenizing, but there is still only ONE underlying engine, i.e. it doesn't magically run the SQL Server 2000 engine!

Comment: Yes Richard, I know that, I was just hoping :)

Comment: @Martin: you were right. It's a SQL 6.5 bug, solved in SQL Server 7.0. I can make that query work on SQL 2000 with compatibility level up to 65.